# Glue like effect

Tags: modifiers, bones

I've been playing recently with rigging and tried to recreate the effect of a glue or goo like material in blender with no much success (still new with it).

To clarify, I've added a pair of bones so I could "stretch" the mesh where I want using them, and what I wanted to achieve is that, when one bone displaces further from the other, the middle region shrinks (kinda like when you glue your fingers together and pull them away, the glue gets thin in the middle until it breaks).

Is this effect achievable?

Comment: Have you tried the _Maintain Volume_ constraint?

Comment: I've tried to use it afer your suggestion, but i fail to see the effect that it gives, i'll check more over it though, thank you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the ***stretch to*** constraint on the middle bone will give the following effect :

[image]

- the middle bone copy the location of the first with parenting (no scale)
- the third bone has no parent or constraint

Comment: That's the effect that i would like to achieve :o though i can't get it to work properly, when i push the extreme bones the mesh deforms equally. Thank you for pointing the constraint :)

Comment: you should have loop cuts in the middle, the bone should be maintaining its volume (leave the constraint settings at default ) ,if still not working comment again

Comment: That is what i was missing :D thank you so much for the help :)